# Will this circuit behave as I am expecting it to?

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, flipflop

I'm an almost total newbie at electronics, but keen to learn more. As a first "serious" project, I wanted to build a device with 4 half-bytes of addressable NOR memory. As a first step to that I've drafted a schematic for the "data entry" block of the circuit, this has:

1. Four flipflips
2. A (momentary) button and LED per flipflop to set and display the state. Push button, corresponding LED turns on.
3. A "global" (momentary) reset button that will set all 4 to 0 (I.E. all the LEDs turn off).
4. A "write" button which will transmit the current state of each flipflop out of this 'block' by setting the output of the corresponding AND gate to the value of the flipflop

The fourth element will be the "write" button that drops whatever value is set in these 4 bits to the storage, after going through a 2-4 addresser.

[image]

The NOR gates are provided by 2x [74HC02](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT02.pdf). I'm supplying 5v to VCC, which is well within the acceptable range defined in that datasheet. The LEDs have forward voltage 1.9v and 20mA max forward current, which I worked out as needing roughly a 155-ohm resistor.

My question I guess is, have I made any design errors that will stop this circuit from functioning as I expect? I've simulated it in software (components not arrived yet) but the simulations don't seem particularly robust (ignoring VCC and GND connections entirely for example, and AFAICT no "you're gonna blow this component mate" calculations...though perhaps I'm using the wrong software.)

Comment: 1) Why use CMOS (74HC02) but also Low power Schottky (74LS08)? Choose **one** technology and stick with that, CMOS is recommended, LS only when you have valid reasons (it is really ancient technology). 2) You have many **floating inputs** (when the switches are not pressed). Avoid that!! You must use a pull-up or pull-down resistor. **Never leave inputs undefined (floating).**

Comment: 3) The series resistors of the LEDs are only 155 ohm 3a) resistors come in E-series (E12, E24) so 155 ohm might not exist 3b) 155 Ohm is **quite low**, you're pulling ~20 mA from the outputs of the 7402 which is not recommended. If you use modern LEDs then 5 mA is more than enough to see them light up. Also, if all the LEDs light up you're exceeding the total maximum supply current of the 74HC02 (which is around 50 mA). The "proper" way is to use a transistor (BJT or MOSFET) to switch the LED's current.

Comment: *have I made any design errors that will stop this circuit from functioning as I expect?* **Yes**, the biggest error is **floating inputs**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thank you! As to why the HC vs LS, plain ignorance only. I had not considered pull downs, but I will add those. I also had not considered the 7402's maximum supply current - would never have thought of that, thank you for mentioning. I'll switch it to controlling transistors and supply the LEDs current from VCC instead. If you make an answer, I can give internet points :D

Comment: *If you make an answer* Sure.

Comment: Your schematic is upside down: VCC goes on the top and GND on the bottom.

Comment: Increase R1 to R4 to keep within the drive capabilities of your chosen gates. (Note traditional TTL can pull low well, but pulls high rather weakly. 74HC is different but can't drive 20mA)

Comment: @BrianDrummond avoiding the need to control via transistors you mean, if they were all dropped to 5ma forward current for example?

Answer (score 4):

1. Why use CMOS (74HC02) but also Low power Schottky (74LS08)? Choose one technology and stick with that, CMOS is recommended, LS only when you have valid reasons (it is really ancient technology).
2. You have many floating inputs (when the switches are not pressed). Avoid that!! You must use a pull-up or pull-down resistor. Never leave inputs undefined (floating). It is a bad habit resulting from the TTL days (a floating TTL input behaved (usually) as a **zero**), it worked but was not recommended. For CMOS with its high impedance inputs, **anything** can happen on a floating node (including receiving (Russian) AM radio stations ;-) ). So tie that input up or down.
3. The series resistors of the LEDs are only 155 ohm
4. resistors come in E-series (E12, E24) so 155 ohm might not exist
5. 155 Ohm is quite low, you're pulling ~20 mA from the outputs of the 7402 which is not recommended. If you use modern LEDs then 5 mA is more than enough to see them light up.
6. Also, if all the LEDs light up you're exceeding the total maximum supply current of the 74HC02 (which is around 50 mA).

The "proper" way is to use a transistor (BJT or MOSFET) to switch the LED's current.